# Rails: Specific Name + ID in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

My problem is that I want a url like `/product/title-1` but I only get `/product/1-title`!
Here is my code in **product.rb:**

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :products do
  resources :comments
end
```

What I must change to get it?

Comment: Change it to return "#{title.parameterize}-#{id}" but be aware this will break your finders (because 'foo-1'.to_i returns 0 where '1-foo'.to_i returns 1). You might want to use something like friendly_id if you want slugs.

Comment: But isn't there an easier solution without friendly_id?